# invisible recaptcha v2 Challenge cut off in mobile

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

The invisible recaptcha v2 challenge is being cut off in mobile view. Sometimes it displays properly in the center but sometimes it's cut off like in the picture below.

I tried playing around the CSS like using transform scale or setting the width but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: why do a invisible recaptcha v2 require user interaction in the first place

Comment: what do you mean? the user clicks the "I'm not a robot" then there are times that the image select challenge shows.